# MVC3 input button triggered by Enter button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, enter, eventtrigger

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 C#.NET web application and I want the *Enter* button to trigger a particular **Save** button on my form.  How would I do that?

Comment: Make your button input type="submit" works. Someone hits enter when a form field has focus, it will submit.

Comment: I have several type=submit buttons on the same form.  I need to single out the "Save" button to work with the Enter button

Comment: Can I ask why multiple submit buttons on a single form?  If the submit buttons do different things what about multiple forms?  If you are capturing which button was clicked in the controller, there may be a better way to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is utilize JavaScript for this one.  Handle the `onkeypress` even of the **form**.  Like so:

```
<form onkeypress="yourKeyPressFunction(event)">
...
</form>
```

Then your `yourKeyPressFunction()` would look something like this:

```
function yourKeyPressFunction(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        // submit or do what you'd like when you hit enter
    }

    // ... so on and so forth
}
```

Comment: that sounds good.  I tried this.form.submit() in the function but threw an error...."this.form is undefined"

Comment: @MikeTWebb To submit a form through JavaScript, there are a few ways.  See this link: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml