# keydown for textboxfor in asp.netmvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i am using asp.net mvc4 and model approach where i dont have ajax call. i want to submit form when enter key is pressed on textboxfor (on password textbox when user press enter it should be submitted)
below is my view and controller code.

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {    
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<table>
    <tr>
        <td  style="width:100px">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>


            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:10px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100px">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        </td>
        <td>


            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:20px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="text-align:right">
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />    
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>            
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]        
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && AuthorizeUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            Session["sessionUserId"] = model.UserName;

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: You need to use scripts for this. See an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609935/mvc3-input-button-triggered-by-enter-button

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the generated HTML too, rather than source, as this is a client-side problem, but you will want to do something like this in a script block on the page:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="password"]').on("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
              // press the submit button
              $('form input[type="submit"]').click();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use as below

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login","ControllerName", new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod="post"})) {
```

This code will direct hit on `Login post type action`

Comment: From the description, I don't think they wanted an ajax solution, just a form submit on Enter press (on the password field).